# Class with list of class within

Tags: c#

I´m new to the OO-Stuff. What I want is follwing:

A class, that contains some properties and additional a list of classes. Here a pseudo code:

[User]

- [Firsname]
- [Lastname]
- ["List of Photos"]

  - [Photo-1]
  - [Photo-2]
  - [Photo-n]

I have a class "User" defined (wihtout my "list of photos"):

```
public class user
{
    string Firstname { get; set; }
    string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a class "Photos":

```
public class photos
{
    string filename { get; set; }
    datetime timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

How can I put "photos" into user, so that I can add and retrieve n photos from a user?

Comment: Change name of `photos` class to `photo` for clear code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [List](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list):

```
public class user
{
    string Firstname { get; set; }
    string Lastname { get; set; }
    List<photos> photos{get;set;}
}
```

**Note: `photos` is not good for naming please rename `photos` to `photo`**

for use:

```
var u=new user();
u.photos=new List<photos>();
u.photos.Add(//add photo)
```

Also you can use:

```
public class user
{
    string Firstname { get; set; }
    string Lastname { get; set; }
    List<photos> photos{get;set;};
    public User()
    {
         photos= new List<photos>();
    }
}
```

and for use:

```
var u=new user();
u.photos.Add(//add photo)
```

Also for naming you can use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Cool. And how I add a "photo" to the list and how I retrieve the filename of the nth-photo? Must I Change code for your implementation (enumerations, etc.)?

Comment: First you should create instance and then use with Add()

Comment: @Leparevilo Also you can new photos in constructor.

Comment: Throughout the Framework, collection properties have no setter (or just a private setter), meaning that you can Add and Remove items in the existing collection but you can't replace the collection itself.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I say use Add()

Comment: Yes, you said use Add but your property still has a setter so you could do this: `myUser.Photos = new List<Photo>();` and that's bad.  Where in the Framework can you do something like that?

Comment: I already did explain.  Your code suggests a public setter on the collection, which is wrong in all but a tiny minority of special cases.

Answer (score 0):

Collection properties should almost universally be read-only.  As such, your classes should look like this:

```
public class Photo
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    private readonly List<Photo> _photos = new List<Photo>();

    public string GivenName { get; set; }

    public string FamilyName { get; set; }

    public List<Photo> Photos
    {
        get
        {
            return this._photos;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want lazy-loading then the User class should look like this:

```
public class User
{
    private List<Photo> _photos;

    public string GivenName { get; set; }

    public string FamilyName { get; set; }

    public List<Photo> Photos
    {
        get
        {
            return this._photos ?? (this._photos = new List<Photo>());
        }
    }
}
```

You could also do away with the field and use a private setter:

```
public class User
{
    public string GivenName { get; set; }

    public string FamilyName { get; set; }

    public List<Photo> Photos { get; private set; }

    public User()
    {
        this.Photos = new List<Photo>();
    }
}
```

In each case, code outside the User class cannot assign directly to the Photos property, meaning that the existing collection cannot be replaced.  You can only get the collection from the property and Add, Remove or whatever.  That's how collection properties work throughout the Framework, e.g. DataSet.Tables, DataTable.Columns, DataTable.Rows, Control.Controls, ComboBox.Items, ListView.Items, etc, etc, and the list goes on.